# Rails 4, how to define Payment type association without creating new model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have model `Payment`, and I need to specify a three payment types. For example: monthly payment, some microtransactions and so on. I think this task does not require a separate table. Maybe there are another way to associate a record with the type of payment? Can I store payment types in `Payment` model, or in yml file?

Comment: You can have a `type` attribute in your `payments` table to deal with this.

Comment: @pavan I should be able to define the possible payment options

Comment: options are fixed or..?

Comment: Then you can have what is suggested.You can map the values with `select` like this `<%= select :type,%w{Monthly Payment ...},:prompt => 'Select',required: true, placeholder: 'Payment Type', class: 'form-control' %>`

Comment: @pavan You know.... You're totally right. Don't know why I dismissed this option. Thank you. Can you create the answer so I can mark it as right answer?

Comment: Yup,sure.I will be posting my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said,you can have a `type` attribute in your `payments` table itself if the payment types are fixed.You can map the `payment types` by using `select` like this

```
<%= select :type,%w{Monthly Payment ...},:prompt => 'Select',required: true, placeholder: 'Payment Type', class: 'form-control' %>
```

This will make sure that the record is associated with one of the payment types.